# Simulator for a robot with a laser scanner for begineers

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new in ROS and I just recently finished the beginner tutorial level using ROS Indigo. I want to know if there is a robot simulator where I can set two robots with a laser scanner in each one for beginners level? because I wanted to use PR2 simulator but it only works for Groovy or early versions of ROS.

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206031/simulator-for-a-robot-with-a-laser-scanner-for-begineers/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I answer to myself: This is a stage simulator that works on Indigo:

http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0